# Insert array to a vector not working

Tags: android, c++11

I have a uint8_t array, and I want to insert it to a vector vec, the code is sort of this:

```
uint8_t arr[] = { 1,2,3 };
std::vector<uint8_t> vec;
vec.insert(vec.begin(), arr, arr+3);
for (auto t : vec) {
    std::cout << unsigned(t) << " ";
}
```

This works fine in http://cpp.sh/, but when I move this into my real code, the compiler throw an error:

```
error: no matching member function for call to 'insert'
    buffer.insert(buffer.end(), hdr->send_data, hdr->send_data + hdr->data_len);
    ~~~~~~~^~~~~~
external/libcxx/include/vector:721:9: note: candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const std::vector<uint8_t>' (aka 'const vector<unsigned char>'), but method is not marked const
        insert(const_iterator __position, _ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last);
        ^
external/libcxx/include/vector:700:14: note: candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const std::vector<uint8_t>' (aka 'const vector<unsigned char>'), but method is not marked const
    iterator insert(const_iterator __position, size_type __n, const_reference __x);
             ^
external/libcxx/include/vector:704:14: note: candidate template ignored: disabled by 'enable_if' [with _InputIterator = const unsigned char *]
             __is_input_iterator  <_InputIterator>::value &&
             ^
external/libcxx/include/vector:692:14: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 3 were provided
    iterator insert(const_iterator __position, const_reference __x);
             ^
external/libcxx/include/vector:694:14: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 3 were provided
    iterator insert(const_iterator __position, value_type&& __x);
             ^
external/libcxx/include/vector:724:14: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 3 were provided
    iterator insert(const_iterator __position, initializer_list<value_type> __il)
```

This code is built in Android AOSP, and the cflags is -std=C++11. I checked the header and it seems followed the C++ standard.

Comment: The error message is mentioning `buffer` that isn't in your sample code. So I guess the code is slightly different. Perhaps `buffer` is a class member and the function you're using it is declared `const`?

Comment: @HappyCactus EXACTLY!! I removed the const and all works fine. How did  you figure that out? The error log makes me think there's no defination. Does this error log has anything to do with the const problem?

Comment: "candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const std::vector<uint8_t>' (aka 'const vector<unsigned char>'), but method is not marked const"

Answer (score 0):

> candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const std::vector' (aka 'const vector'), but method is not marked const

You're probably trying to modify the `buffer` member from a method marked `const`.

Either remove the `const` signature from your method, or use the `mutable` keyword (but it depends on the purpose of your class method, pay attention).

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of a tangent to your original question, and what you have obviously works now that it's non-const, but a safer way to copy a C-style array to a `std::vector` is a slight variation of what you already have.

```
std::vector<uint8_t> vec;
uint8_t arr[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
size_t arrSize = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(uint8_t);
vec.insert(vec.end(), arr, arr + arrSize);
```

This method will work for any type of objects not just uint8_t and you don't have to think about how many elements `arr[]` has since you are calculating the size.